# Maven compiler plugin error v3.0.3

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am new to maven installation. While executing a .bat file which installs maven, I am getting the below error. Could you please check :

```
     Launching environment tests
     checking Java 4 compile, java 4 run
     [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
     [ERROR] Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
     The system cannot find the path specified.

     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default
     -compile) on project devenv-validate: Compilation failure
     [ERROR] Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
     [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
     [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
     [ERROR]
     [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
     [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
     [ERROR]
     [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following arti
     cles:
     [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
     checking Java 4 compile, java 6 run
     [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
     [ERROR] Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
     The system cannot find the path specified.

     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default
     -compile) on project devenv-validate: Compilation failure
     [ERROR] Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
     [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
     [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
     [ERROR]
     [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
     [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
     [ERROR]
     [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following arti
     cles:
     [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
     checking Java 6 compile, java 6 run

     -------------------------------------------------------
      T E S T S
     -------------------------------------------------------
     Running TestDevEnvValidator
     Java version  : Actual [1.6.0_20], expected [1.6.0_20]
     Java compiler : Actual [6], expected [6]
     Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec

     Results :

     Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

     Press any key to continue . . .
```

Can anyone please have a look and say why it is failing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run the same mvn command with the -X option and post the debug log. The problem is that Maven is not able to execute javac, but it is unclear why until you enable debug logging.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not „_a .bat file which installs maven_“ you executed but Maven (`mvn ...`) itself. Before running it with `-X` execute `mvn --version` and add the result to your question.

Answer (score 1):

> The system cannot find the path specified.

If you are using Windows, please check if the path specified for system variables: Path, JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME, M2.

Check out this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm